# Populate combox with a type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm working on a new application that use a lot of reflection and have some problem to populate a combobox.

I have a parameter class with some information about a parameter for specific method:

```
   class Parameter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Type Type { get; set; }

        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a view with a DataTemplateSelector that pick different DataTemplated depending on the parameter type:

```
class ParameterDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StringDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BoolDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EnumDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate NullTypeDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var parameter = item as Parameter;
        if (parameter.Type == null)
        {
            return NullTypeDataTemplate;
        }
        if (parameter.Type == typeof (int)
            || parameter.Type == typeof(string))
        {
            return StringDataTemplate;
        }
        if (parameter.Type.BaseType == typeof (Enum))
        {
            return EnumDataTemplate;
        }
        return BoolDataTemplate;      
    }
}
```

And in my XAML I have my different templates:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stuff.UI.Views.ParametersView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:dataTemplateSelectors="clr-namespace:Stuff.UI.Common.DataTemplateSelectors"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StringDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BoolDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding >>something<<}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NullDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="NULL TYPE"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <dataTemplateSelectors:ParameterDataTemplateSelector
            StringDataTemplate="{StaticResource StringDataTemplate}"
            BoolDataTemplate="{StaticResource BoolDataTemplate}"
            EnumDataTemplate="{StaticResource EnumDataTemplate}"
            NullTypeDataTemplate="{StaticResource NullDataTemplate}"
            x:Key="ParameterDataTemplateSelector"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <StackPanel Background="#dddddd">
            <Label Content="Parameters" Background="#e1db45"></Label>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ParameterDataTemplateSelector}">
            </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So the problem is my combobox here:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding >>something<<}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

How can I populate it when I only have a type (and I know by checking that it is a Enum type)? Or should I do it in code-behind in some way? I'm a bit lost here and pretty new to MVVM and WPF in general.

Comment: What are you trying to populate it with exactly?

Comment: All the different enum values for that type, say for example I have a enum Contacts { John, Erik }. Then I want the view to populate the combobox with John and Erik by looking at the type.

Comment: You could certainly try the `ObjectDataProvider` suggested in the answer. I'm not sure how/if that would work in a dynamic situation, but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a converter to get the list of enum values from the enum type.  Something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Type,Converter={StaticResource EnumToValuesConverter}}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:EnumToValuesConverter x:Key="EnumToValuesConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

The converter should just call ["GetEnumValues"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the enum type:

```
public class EnumToValuesConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var enumType = (Type)value;
        return enumType.GetEnumValues();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this:
[Bind to an enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb613576(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should use ObjectDataProvider.

Comment: This is nifty, but I don't think it applies to the OP, because it requires a compile-time type.